# POCO C++ Library, HTTPResponse bad status

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I am trying to unzip a file from a network stream using POCO C++ library on Ubuntu Linux, but decompressing fails with "Illegal state" exception. `HTTPResponse` status and reason are **302 Moved Temporarily**. At the same time i can download and unzip the link with a browser. What should i do with `HTTPClientSession` when `HTTPResponse` is in such state?

```
  ...
HTTPResponse res;
  std::istream& rs = h_ses.receiveResponse (res);
  if (res.getStatus () != HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK) {
    poco_error (logger, "http response status: " + std::to_string (res.getStatus ()) + " " + res.getReason ());
  }
  if (!rs) {
    poco_error (logger, "responese stream is in bad state: " + std::to_string (rs.rdstate()));
  }
  Decompress dec (rs, target_dir_.native ());
  poco_debug (logger, "Unzipping: " + dl + " ...");

  dec.EError += Poco::Delegate<Addon_Loader, std::pair<const Poco::Zip::ZipLocalFileHeader, const std::string> >(this, &Addon_Loader::on_decompress_error);
  dec.decompressAllFiles ();
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with HTTPStreamFactory; here's a full example:

```
#include "Poco/URI.h"
#include "Poco/URIStreamOpener.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPStreamFactory.h"
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace Poco;
using namespace Poco::Net;

int main()
{
        URIStreamOpener opener;
        opener.registerStreamFactory("http", new HTTPStreamFactory);
        URI uri("http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F");
        std::auto_ptr<std::istream> pStr(opener.open(uri));
        StreamCopier::copyStream(*pStr.get(), std::cout);
        return 0;
}
```

If you have to use HTTPClientSession, look at how [HTTPStreamFactory](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/src/HTTPStreamFactory.cpp#L120-L132) does it.

Answer (score 1):

In the `302` response, there should be a header field which points out the new location. You simply have to follow that link instead.

See e.g. [this link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3), or [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), and of course the actual [HTTP 1.1 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).